# Obj C: Creating a standard try-catch-block for use through the application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I am building a app with many different parts which access remote api calls (both my own, and others). There are many errors that might happen, and to exacerbate the problem, different libraries handle these errors differently.

Essentially, i would like to use the same error handling blocks for all these remote calls.

This is how i would do it with Ruby, but i am not that sure how to manipulate objective c in the same manner

```
  //universal function to handle standard remote errors across errors
  def universal_handling
    begin
      yield
    rescue Exception => e
      // handle different exceptions accordingly  
      // allow crash if unexpected exception
    end
  end

  //how i would use the above block
  universal_handling{  //any of my remote call here  }
```

So, i have 2 questions (sample code very much appreciated)

1. How would I write the equivalent code in Objective-C? It is critical that I can use the same handling block throughout the app
2. In iOS dev, is this good practice?

Thanks for any help rendered! Error handling can be a major pain in the ass, so i do want to get this right early on =)

Notes:

1. Blocks are perfectly fine. I am not intending to support < 4.2 versions.
2. I read most of the articles out there, but none answers how you can use blocks to write "wrappers" for a specific set of calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something very similar with blocks:

```
typedef void(^WrappableBlock)(void);

^(WrappableBlock block) {
  @try {
    block();
  }
  @catch(...)
  }
    //handle exception
  }
}
```

However, it's very important to realize that the Cocoa (and CocoaTouch) libraries are *not* exception-safe. Throwing an exception through Cocoa frameworks will lead to all sorts of problems as the frameworks will not properly handle or clean up from the exceptions, leaving your application in a possibly inconsistent state. The correct Cocoa-style is to use `NSError` and return flags to indicate error conditions. This is neither better nor worse than using exceptions, just a different philosophy.

To do something similar to your `universal_handling` with `NSError` is not quite so straight forward because it will require that anything you call comply with the `NSError` pattern. That said:

```
typedef BOOL(^WrappableBlock)(NSError**);

^(WrappableBlock block, NSError **err) {
  BOOL success = block(err);
  if(!success) {
    // handle error
  }

  return success;
}
```

would wrap any method that takes *just* an `NSError**` and returns a `BOOL` to indicate the presence of an error. Obviously the utility of this wrapper is limited as you'll have to wrap any interesting method in an other block to handle any other parameters. Of course, since it's the `NSError**` pattern, you can always just handle the errors when/where you want and pass `NULL` as the `NSError**` parameter where you don't care (ignoring the return value).

One final note: if you are using libraries that  may throw exceptions, you *must* catch those exceptions within the scope of the library call and handle them. Do not let the exceptions propagate as they might then propagate through Cocoa framework code. Thus, the utility of the `universal_handling` block you propose is limited.

Comment: Barry, since your answer, i have done a lot of reading and thinking about nserrors and exceptions. i am still a little confused about how exactly to use nserror - do you mind adding an example to share how it would look like if nserror was used instead? Thank you!

Comment: ming, I added an example of `NSError` usage. Good question; I've never considered using a wrapping handler like this for `NSError`, so what I've added is my first thoughts on the mater.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you [this nice cocoawithlove article](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/handling-unhandled-exceptions-and.html) that explains how to handle unhandled exceptions in Objective-C and also how to recover from an exception instead of "just" crashing. That could be a good alternative to what you are looking for.

I'm afraid that Objective-C not being as *dynamic* as ruby, that is a *bit* harder to do.

Would love to see a good block based implementation too, if that's possible, even If I'm not using them yet, because of previous version compatibility.

Comment: Thanks vincent! I read it before, but i was really uncomfortable with it. It essentially catchs all the unhandled exceptions, but i rather those crash with a full stack trace. What I need is to be able to write handles for a very specific type of functions which generate similar errors. I know it is harder in obj-c, which is why i am stuck. my obj-c-fu is not that good... ;)